# Visual Studio Code WSL can't compile files in /mnt/c/OneDrive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I usually store all my programming files in One Drive so that I can access them anywhere I go. But now I need to be able to compile my c++ programs on Linux machines. So I tried using visual studio code in WSL mode but when I try to compile and debug my code I am told that it can't find any *.cpp fies in the specified location, yet the files are clearly there. If I run the compile command on my own in the ubuntu window it works just fine. When I moved the files from /mnt to my home directory everything worked fine. Why would my compile command work just fine when I use it from the ubuntu window, but now work when VS Code tries to do it? Any ideas?

Here is my task.json file and launch.json file:

`task.json`

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${cwd}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${cwd}/main"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

`launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${cwd}/main",
            "args": ["test1.txt"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well even without WSL using OneDrive for storing your source code is problematic. In Visual Studio generating packages for Windows Store fails if your code is in OneDrive. In IntelliJ many issues occur also. GitHub now have private repositories for free and are many other options to avoid using OneDrive for your source code